# Structure of models in Django

Tags: django-models

I've got for things that I want to model: vaccines, countries, diseases and medicines.

A disease is in N countries
A medicine cures N diseases
A vaccine prevents N diseases

My primary search method will be by country, listing vaccines and medicines through the disease connection.

I thought I'd do this by this model:

```
class Country(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Disease(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.ManyToManyField(Country)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Vaccine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    diseases = models.ManyToManyField(Disease, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Medicine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    diseases = models.ManyToManyField(Disease, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

And I search like this:

```
def vacc_for_country(request, country_id):
    diseases = Disease.objects.filter(countries__pk=country_id)
    vaccines = Vaccine.objects.filter(id__in=[d.id for d in [v.diseases for v in Vaccine.objects.all()]])
    return serialize(vaccines)
```

but that doesn't work, I get: AttributeError at /vaccines/seek/countryId/3
'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'id'.

So how do I go from country_id to a list of vaccines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no clue what you were going for there.

```
Vaccine.objects.filter(diseases__country__id=country_id)
```

Comment: Oh, it was that easy. Thanks a lot :) This is my first Django-app, haven't wrapped my head around the filter arguments yet.